# MVC FileStreamResult is not downloading file with custom file name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filestream

The pdf downloads fine but with a random name - 9619012021194536.pdf
I'm trying to set a custom name but it is not working.
The downloaded file still has a random name instead of the custom name being set in code.

```
public ActionResult Appointment(int id)
        {
            Stream stream = null;
            string fileName = "";

            try
            {
                stream = GenerateAppointmentReport(id);
                fileName = id + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".pdf";                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName))
            { FileDownloadName = fileName };
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @gunr2171 The downloaded file has the random name instead of the custom name set in the code.

Comment: The Id you are getting doesn't look as random as you might think. There is a date/time in the number. Are you getting an exception (and then swallowing it)? What is the value of `fileName` when you hit the last line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
public ActionResult Appointment(int id)
{
  Stream stream = null;
  string fileName = "";

  try
  {
     stream = GenerateAppointmentReport(id);
     fileName = id + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".pdf";                    
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
                    
  }
  return new FileStreamResult(stream, "binary") { FileDownloadName = fileName };
}
```

I used this code and the file was downloaded with the specific name I mentioned.

Comment: I was  using "application/pdf" and then switch to "binary" and I got error "the header contains invalid values at index 0 'binary'"

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the data in a temporary object of type `GridView` and then write the object to the output stream like this:

```
    public ActionResult Appointment(int id)
    {
    
    GridView gridview = new GridView();
    gridview.DataSource = fileData; //fileData is an object with all the properties
    gridview.DataBind();
    
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    
tmpfileName = id + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = " + tmpfileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.Charset = "";
    
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        gridview.RenderControl(htw);
                        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
    
    return RedirectToAction("Appointment"); // To another/same action
    }
```